# Why doesn't string-normalize-whitespace type check with keyword arg?

Tags: types, scheme, racket, typed-racket

In typed racket,

I have

```
  `(: collapse ((Listof Expansion) -> Expansion))
   ; flatten a list of expansions into a single expansion representing the whole thing--
  (define (collapse expansions)
     (letrec: ([token : String   (foldl (λ: ([e : Expansion] [working : String]) (string-append working (token-of e))) "" expansions)]
        [normalized-token  : String (string-normalize-spaces token)]
        [lexicon : Lexicon (foldl (λ: ([e : Expansion] [working : Lexicon])
                                    (merge-lexica working (lexicon-of e))) 
                           (empty-lexicon) 
                           expansions)])
      (make-expansion token lexicon)))`
```

which gives me

`Type Checker: Expected String, but got (case-> (String [#:repeat? Any] [#:trim? Any] -> String) (String (U Regexp String) [#:repeat? Any] [#:trim? Any] -> String) (String (U Regexp String) String [#:repeat? Any] [#:trim? Any] -> String)) in: (string-normalize-spaces token #:trim #f)`

This checks out fine if I remove the keyword arg (though, of course, then it doesn't actually do what I want).

Upgrading to the latest release (shocker!) improved matters--resolved my `require` problem, but I'm clearly still missing something.

Comment: Can you post a more complete example of the code? It's hard to tell what's going on from the first snippet (and it's hard to reproduce). Also, in Racket v6.0 the `string-normalize-spaces` function should come with a type, so you shouldn't need to use `require/typed`.

Comment: Just checked and saw I'm on an old version of Racket, so I'm updating now, and maybe that'll be that!

Comment: Typed Racket is not Scheme; suggest removing the Scheme tag.

Answer (score 1):

Upgraded to Racket 6.0 and removed the `require`, eliminated the errors.